# How to place Dojo Toolkit outside a WAR file to shorten building time?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, dojo, tomcat7

Good day, I'm developing a simple Java EE web application in NetBeans 7.2.1 which uses Dojo Toolkit 1.8.1 and which runs on Appache Tomcat 7.0. I included Dojo Tolkit into the application's resources folder but building the app takes long time as Dojo Toolkit contains many files. Is it posible to place Dojo Toolkit outside the WAR file so that building doesn't take that long and I'm still able to use Dojo in my web application? Each time I need to debug the application I need to rebuild it so I'm waiting a lot. Please advise. Many thanks in advance. Vojtech

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that works very well for me is to build a separate dojo web app and deploy along side or on another instance of Tomcat.

The reason being, cross-domain issues can be hard to debug and you get more control over the build, version, modules etc.

You can also deploy dojo to apache httpd if you have access or have installed it on the server.

when you load the toolkit, you would use either`http://<servername>:<tomcatport>/<context>` or if on Apache httpd simply`"/dtk" or "/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"` etc.

I use "dtk" as the context so dojo.js resides at `http://<servername>:<tomcatport>/dtk/dojo/dojo.js` and usually my application is compiled as dtk##1.8.1.war for Tomcat 7 - the ## indicates to tc that you would like a that displayed as the version.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can load Dojo from a CDN and not include the dojo code in your WAR.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

http://dojotoolkit.org/download/
```

Answer (score 0):

On application start you should add something like

```
import org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader;
...
tomcat.addWebapp('/dojolib', '/path/to/dojolib');
```

I know exactly where to add it with Grails, but this may give you direction with Java http://nileshk.com/2010/08/25/emdedding-apache-tomcat-7-0.html.

Answer (score 0):

you can place it anywhere in WAR file but make sure not to include that folder in the build path